# Intersection of two balls

Tags: geometry

The following calculation seems to give an absurd result, but I cannot figure
 out the mistake.

Two balls are given, the first one with mid-point (-1/3/1) and radius 6, the 
 second one with mid-point (4/5/1) and radius 2. The distance of the mid-points
 is the length of the vector (5/2/0) , which is $\sqrt{29} = 5,385$

Since the distance lies between the difference and the sum of 6 and 2, the balls
 should intersect. I tried to calculate the radiud and the mid-point of the intersecting circle in two different
 ways :

1) The radius of the intersection circle should be both $\sqrt{36-x^2}$ and
    $\sqrt{4-(\sqrt{29}-x)^2}$ , where x is the distance of the mid-point 
    (-1/3/1) from the plane containing the intersection circle.
    The solution of the equation is 5,6637 which is greater than the distance
    of the mid-points.

2) The equations for the balls are

$$(x_1+1)^2+(x_2-3)^2+(x_3-1)^2 = 36$$

and

$$(x_1-4)^2+(x_2-5)^2+(x_3-1)^2 = 4$$

subtracting both sides gives

$$10x_1+4x_2-31 = 32$$

so

$$10x_1+4x_2 = 63$$

The distance of the mid-point (-1/3/1) from this plane is 5,6637, so I got the
same result as in 1)

Where did I make a mistake ?

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct. Draw a picture that shows whats happening in the vertical plane containing the two center points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One sphere has radius 6, which is greater than the distance between the two spheres. So the small (radius 2) sphere sits mostly inside the larger one, and the circle of intersection is not between the two centers.